# US Port of Entry would be LAX and destination is Boston. Any issues to be expected to with Port of Entry Process?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, f1-visas, lax

I am attending Boston University in Massachusetts this fall and flying from India to Hong Kong to LAX to Boston on an F1 Visa. I have a long layover of 20 hours at LAX and, since the US considers my Port of Entry to be my first entry port, I'll have to go through the Port Of Entry Process at LAX. Are there going to be any hiccups getting the process done at LAX instead of Boston in the midst of the long layover?

Comment: What hiccups are you worried about?

Comment: @phoog Probably being denied entry to the US since, my university is on the east coast and I'll be entering on the West Coast and have a long layover subsequently

Comment: No. That isn't an issue. If you're a bona fide student you can enter the US via any port. That's how the system is designed

Comment: Why would your entering on the west coast lead an immigration officer to deny entry?  They know that the earth is round.

Comment: Everything you described sounds pretty normal. I wouldn't expect any hiccups. I should mention one wrinkle, though. You will need to pick up any checked-in bags after arriving on an international flight in LAX, pass them through the U.S. customs in LAX, then check in the bags again for the domestic flight to Boston. Ask your airline for the detailed instructions which may vary.

Comment: There is NO difference between going through immigration in LAX vs BOS. The same rules apply. In fact, it helps you: once you made it through immigration and customs you have properly entered the US. You are free to leave the airport do some sightseeing or grab a hotel  for the night. You just need to be back a couple of hours before your flight to Boston. There are some nuances about your luggage, but if your bags are checked through, you can simply drop of them after customs and don't need to lug them around.

Comment: @Hilmar simply drop them off after customs - it should be that easy everywhere, but LAX is extremely disorganized.

Comment: I think the 20 hour layover might be a feature rather than a bug - God forbid something does happen between Hong Kong and LAX - flight delay or delay in customs or who knows what - you've got a lot of slack time to resolve it before your final leg.

Answer (score 18):

No, US immigration officials know that you must complete immigration at the first US airport you arrive in (i.e. there is no "sterile transit" in the US). That means that they are set up to handle this and should not give you any trouble.

The fact that your layover is 20 hours is irrelevant to the border officials. Being granted entry to the US grants access to all 50 states, DC, and Puerto Rico without additional interviews or applications. Since no distinction is made between access to Massachusetts versus California, they will not care how long you plan to stay in California as long as your intent to start your studies in Boston on-time is legitimate. This also means that you are free, at any time during your studies, to go to Texas for a rodeo or go to Alaska for the Iditarod as long as you maintain your studies.

Make sure you have evidence (e.g. tickets) of your passage to Boston and your student status in case you are asked.

Have fun at BU!

Comment: Actually, it's only the 50 states, DC, and PR that are on the single immigration system. Other US territories have different rules (for example, British Overseas Citizens of the British Virgin Islands can enter the US Virgin Islands with only a passport, but require a police certificate to enter the rest of the US; Malaysian Citizens can only enter Guam and the Northern Mariana Islands without a visa; and British Overseas Citizens of Bermuda can't travel to American Samoa without a visa, but don't even need ESTA for the rest of the US.)

Comment: Just be aware that if you choose to go Boston -> Fairbanks for the Iditarod, your flight will take nearly as long as the Mumbai -> LAX flight. (17 hrs BOS->FAI v 24 hrs BOM->LAX).